# What's the correct way to use win32file.ReadFile to get the output from a pipe?

Tags: python, windows, pywin32, readfile

I'm using the [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) extensions to access the win32 API under Python. I'm new at doing Windows programming in Python -- I'm a POSIX guy -- so I may be doing things in a bone-headed manner.

I'm trying to use the [`win32file.ReadFile`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/win32file__ReadFile_meth.html) function properly, and I'm having some trouble interpreting the possible result codes.

I'm calling the function like this:

```
result, data = win32file.ReadFile(child_stdout_r, 4096, None)
```

I'm reading the output from a child process that I launch. I get good data, but I'm concerned that there may be more data in the pipe than 4096 characters. (And I'd rather do this right, instead of just picking an arbitrarily large buffer size.)

In the case where there's more than 4096 characters to read, I would need to run `win32file.ReadFile` multiple times until I exhaust the pipe. To find out whether I need to run `ReadFile` multiple times, I need to interpret the result code.

The [ActiveState docs](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/win32file__ReadFile_meth.html) say that:

> The result is a tuple of (hr, string/PyOVERLAPPEDReadBuffer), where hr may be 0, ERROR_MORE_DATA or ERROR_IO_PENDING.

Since I'm setting the overlapped value to None in the function call, I think I don't need to worry about any `PyOVERLAPPEDReadBuffer` stuff. (And since I'm getting valid data, I think I'm right.)

I have two problems with the hr result variable:

1. I can't find the values of the constants ERROR_MORE_DATA or ERROR_IO_PENDING anywhere.
2. The ActiveState docs seem to imply that 0 is success and the constants (whatever they are) indicate failure. The [Microsoft docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365467(VS.85).aspx) state that 0 indicates failure, non-zero indicates success, and you need to run GetLastError to find out more.

What's the correct way to do this?

**EDITED TO ADD:** I'm not using subprocess because I need to add the child process to a job object I create. The goal is to have all child processes die immediately if the parent process dies. By adding the child process to the job object, the child process will be terminated when the last handle to the job object is closed. The handle, held by the parent, will be closed when the parent exits. All of this, as far as I can tell, precludes me from using subprocess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For error codes, try `winerror.ERROR_MORE_DATA` and `winerror.ERROR_IO_PENDING`

My interpretation of the `ActiveState` docs is the same as yours.  It sounds like the wrapper works slightly differently than the native API.

I haven't actually tried this.

Comment: I think I love you, jdigital. ;-) Thanks!

Comment: I must admit that's a first for me on SO.  Blush ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Consider using `subprocess` to launch the process. It will give you a set of file-like objects that you can use to talk with the other app.

The `.terminate()` method of the Popen object will allow you to terminate the process if you are running 2.6+.

Comment: There's lots of ways to kill the child process if the parent is able to clean up, but I need to kill the child process if the parent dies for any reason at all, including being terminated with Windows' equivalent of Unix's "kill -9" -- which precludes any cleanup actions.

Answer (score -1):

note that ReadFile is defined as:

```
(int, string) = ReadFile(hFile, buffer/bufSize , overlapped)
```

where...

```
hFile = PyHANDLE
```

which is any windows handle (can be file, process, thread...)

```
buffer/bufSize = PyOVERLAPPEDReadBuffer
```

which, according to documentation automatically allocates contents of hFile regardless if it overlaps or not.

```
overlapped=None [=PyOVERLAPPED]
```

you can allocate an additional object to take any extra data, beyond the overlapped (buffer/bufSize) if you wish, but by default this is NULL.

So - you can basically call `ReadFile` like:

```
ReadFile(child_stdout_r, 0, None)
```

and the object you assign it to will contain the full contents of the file handle.

Comment: `ReadFile(child_stdout_r, 0, None)` just returns an empty string on python 2.7.9. This answers is wrong.

Comment: actually you just didnt read my answer - I was giving an example. the answer is correct, for the version of python it was asked for.