# python - Read file using win32file.ReadFile

Tags: python, readfile, pywin32

Similar Question:

[What's the correct way to use win32file.ReadFile to get the output from a pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069344/whats-the-correct-way-to-use-win32file-readfile-to-get-the-output-from-a-pipe)

The issue I have however was not answered in that question. When I call

```
result, data = win32file.ReadFile(my_file, 4096, None)
```

result is always 0 which according to documentation means success:

```
The result is a tuple of (hr, string/PyOVERLAPPEDReadBuffer), where hr may be 0, 
ERROR_MORE_DATA or ERROR_IO_PENDING.
```

Even if I set the buffer to 10 and the file is much bigger the result is 0 and data is a string containing the first 10 characters.

```
result, buf = win32file.ReadFile(self._handle, 10, None)  
while result == winerror.ERROR_MORE_DATA:            
    result, data = win32file.ReadFile(self._handle, 2048, None)
    buf += data   
    print "Hi"
return result, buf
```

"Hi" is never printed even if the file clearly contains more data.
The problem I have is how can I ensure that I'm reading the whole file without using a ridiculous large buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was already observed is that if the `win32file.ReadFile` result value `hr` is 0, then that means success. This is exactly the opposite from the win32 api documentation that says 0 means an error occurred.

To determine how many bytes were read you need to check the length of the returned string. If it is same size as the buffer size, then there might be more data. If it is smaller, the whole file has been read:

```
def readLines(self):
    bufSize = 4096
    win32file.SetFilePointer(self._handle, 0, win32file.FILE_BEGIN)
    result, data = win32file.ReadFile(self._handle, bufSize, None) 
    buf = data
    while len(data) == bufSize:            
        result, data = win32file.ReadFile(self._handle, bufSize, None)
        buf += data
    return buf.split('\r\n')
```

You need to add error handling to this, eg. check result if it actually is 0 and if not take according measures.

Comment: on buf.split('\r\n'), "a bytes like object is required, not str"

Answer (score 0):

Use PeekNamedPipe to see how much data is left on the pipe to read.

```
result, buf = win32file.ReadFile(self._handle, bufSize, None)
_, nAvail, nMessage = win32pipe.PeekNamedPipe(self._handle, 0)
while nAvail > 0:
    result, data = win32file.ReadFile(self._handle, bufSize, None)
    buf += data
    _, nAvail, nMessage = win32pipe.PeekNamedPipe(self._handle, 0)
```

This will tell you the total amount of data (`nAvail`) on the pipe and the amount of data left to read for the current message (`nMessage`). You can then either use a buffer of sufficient size to read the remaining data or read in chunks if you prefer.

If using message mode you probably want to read a single message at a time. If you can't predict the maximum message size then first read 0 bytes to block until a message is available, then query the message size and read those many bytes:

```
# Block until data is available (assumes PIPE_WAIT)
result, _ = win32file.ReadFile(self._handle, 0, None)
# result should be 234
_, nAvail, nMessage = win32pipe.PeekNamedPipe(self._handle, 0)
result, buf = win32file.ReadFile(self._handle, nMessage, None)
```

If using PIPE_NOWAIT then poll for messages using `PeekNamedPipe` and only read when `nMessage > 0`

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution by beginner_ and got the error message "a bytes like object is required, not str" when calling buf.split('\r\n')

I printed str(buf) and saw it's in the form of "b'bufstring'"

As a hack I changed the line to `return str(buf)[2:-1].split('\\r\\n')` and it works perfectly now.

Comment: Likely due to my code being ancient and python2.7-based.