# How to convert result from win32file.ReadFile to something readable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I made a named pipe and its working fine: the client is writing to it and the server is receiving it.

How do I convert a PyOVERLAPPEDReadBuffer object to the actual data that I want? Im passing a double with size of 8 (i think).

The docs im using: http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32file__ReadFile_meth.html

```
hr, thing = win32file.ReadFile(pipe, 8)
print("hr: " + str(hr))
print("thing: " + str(thing))
```

output

```
hr: 0
thing: b'\xbc\x91y\xe4\x0f\x06\xeb?'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python - Read file using win32file.ReadFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29910861/python-read-file-using-win32file-readfile)

Comment: I saw that. Im not sure, what does the split() method do and where are the docs for it?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split

Comment: ok, even if I split it using \x as the delimiter, its still just a collection of garbage. I need the double... I dont think that question answered that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case `thing` is Bytes and you expect a `double`, you could use [`struct.unpack`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/struct.html?highlight=unpack#struct.unpack) to convert:

```
>>> thing = b'\xbc\x91y\xe4\x0f\x06\xeb?'
>>> import struct
>>> d, = struct.unpack('d', thing)
>>> d
0.84449
```